# while adding an item to the cart using JS buy SDK addLineItems (shopify) for the 2nd time. I'm getting an error saying "checkout is already completed"

Tags: sdk, shopify, shopify-app

While adding item to the cart the second time, It throws an error
Error: [{"message":"Checkout is already completed.","locations":[{"line":1,"column":3286}],"path":["checkoutLineItemsAdd"]}]

```
addItemToCheckout = async (variantId, quantity) => {
    const lineItemsToAdd = [
      {
        variantId,
        quantity: parseInt(quantity, 10),
      },
    ];   
    try{
    const checkout = await client.checkout.addLineItems(
      this.state.checkout.id,
      lineItemsToAdd
    );
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
    // this.setState({ checkout: checkout });
    
    this.openCart();
  };




 <Button w="10rem" backgroundColor="#FF38BD" color="white" _hover={{ opacity: '70%' }}
              onClick={() => addItemToCheckout(product.variants[0]?.id, 2)}>
              Add To Cart
          </Button>
```

Comment: I think the error message is misleading. Are you sure that the checkout id that you're passing is correct, and the variant id is correct?

Comment: yes, it is valid.

Comment: Could be that the variantId is already there and you need to use the updateCartLine instead?